# UIPickerView with empty arrays

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

I've set up a UIPickerView successfully, but I'm wondering about the best way to handle the case when the data is initially empty. For my current iteration I use the following code for the pickerdelegate

```
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row                           forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{ 
    if ([flash_cards count])
    {
        return [[flash_cards allKeys] objectAtIndex:row];
    }

return @"";
}
```

where

```
 flash_cards = NSMutableDictionary *
```

Whenever I try to scroll it creates an error of indexoutofbounds which is only logical. How do I handle the case of an empty array?

EDIT:

Also as part of the code I implemented the following

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponen: (NSInteger)component
  {
     return [flash_cards count];

  }

  #pragma mark Picker Data Source Methods
  - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
  {
   return 1;
  }
```

Comment: **STRONG NOTE** Using an `NSMutableDictionary` `allKeys` property as the datasource for anything is a dangerous idea. There is no guarantee that an immutable dictionary's `allKeys` array will be ordered the same every time, let alone a mutable. You should call `allKeys` once, sort it, and then save it. Use that saved array as the datasource. That way when someone selects the 3rd item you know the 3rd item in that saved array is what they meant to select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem you should return 1 instead 0 in the method `numberOfRowsInComponent` from the  `UIPickerViewDataSource` when the array is empty, like the example below:

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [self.myArray count] == 0 ? 1 : [self.myArray count];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also implement the [UIPickerViewDataSource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIPickerViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIPickerViewDataSource) methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

You can still use `flash_cards` (or `[flash_cards count]`) to derive the return values of these methods; if your data is empty, you can return 0, then later call `-reloadAllComponents` on your picker view when you get data loaded.

Comment: I updated what I originally had. Whenever the array is empty, it raises an error. When I replace return [flash_cards count] with return 0, it still has the same error